# Internet Explorer fails to load css files

Tags: css, internet-explorer

**Situation:**

I have a PHP written page, wich will include a css via

```
<style type="text/css">@import url(/css/my.css);</style>
```

Afterwards (and on demand) a javascript file is loaded, that opens a new "Window" where the css declarations would be used.

This works in all Browsers except Internet Explorer (7-9).

**Problem:**

According to the IE Developer Tools (F12) the css file is loaded and I can see all declarations made within this file (they are correct), but when the new window is displayed, the css declarations do not seem to be in effect.

***"Solution":***

Deselecting (and reselecting them, even if it's not necessary) some of the rules of the given CSS File in the CSS-Tab of the IE Developer Tools make the page "render" correctly.

**Question:**

Where does this behaviour come from, and how do i get rid of this?

**Additional Information:**

I do not have more than 4095 (not even counting all in all CSS Files alltogether) selectors (in fact I have less than 2.5k) and I only load less than 31 (exactly 7) different CSS Files.

**As requested:**

```
<div class="navigate">
<div class="nav-slider">
  <div class="nav-slider-left">
    <span role="button" class="nav-link nav-page-back">&lt;</span>

    <div class="page-number">
      <span>1 of 1</span>
    </div><span role="button" class="nav-link nav-page-next">&gt;</span><span role=
    "button" class="nav-link nav-now">&acirc;&mdash;</span><span role="button" class=
    "nav-link nav-prev-week">&lt;&lt;</span><span role="button" class=
    "nav-link nav-prev-day">&lt;</span>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-slider-content">
    <div class="nav-slider-bar">
      <a class="nav-slider-button"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-slider-right">
    <span role="button" class="nav-link nav-next-day">&gt;</span><span role="button"
    class="nav-link nav-next-week">&gt;&gt;</span><span role="button" class=
    "nav-link nav-zoomIn">+</span><span role="button" class=
    "nav-link nav-zoomOut">-</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

(i have reduced the HTML Code to the relevant part [ExtJS is creating a massive amount of structure around the given code)

[CSS Declarations are here](http://pastebin.com/SkZieMCR)

Comment: This sounds weird. Can you show some of the rules and the HTML they apply to? Are you sure your HTML and CSS are valid (or at least do not contain any egregious structural problems)?

Comment: I added them to the first post. CSS and HTML should be valid, or at least not totally wrong ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but it might be a caching problem since your styles are interpreted as inline-css and won't be saved when you open a new window. Did you try to use:

```
<link href="yourcssfile.css" type"text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

> UPDATE:
>   It seems to be a bug. I found your problem in this article (point5). Solution is in there aswell.

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml

Comment: The "Window" i refer to is in fact an ExtJS-Window, so i do not leave the current page.