# Reduce a div to the size of the image it contains

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I need to center an image atop another image, both vertically and horizontally.
The following code works fine in Chrome, but fails in IE because the container DIV stretches to fill the remaining horizontal space.

**Displayed in IE8:**

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color:#180e0b;
  font-family:DejaVu Sans Mono ;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
}

.text {
  float:left;
  padding-right: 6px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: brown;
}

.thumb {
  display: block;
}

.loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Doomero</div>
<div class="container">
  <img class="thumb" src="http://www.principiaprogrammatica.com/thumb.png"/>
  <img class="loading" src="http://www.principiaprogrammatica.com/rolling.gif"/>
</div>
```

I am after a **CSS** solution with **IE** compatibly and **without hard-coded fixed values**.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830714/internet-explorer-fails-to-load-css-files

Comment: Read Internet Explorer & CSS issues http://www.webcredible.com/blog/internet-explorer-css-issues/

Comment: Try to use `float:left;` instead of `display:inline-block`.

Comment: My problem is regarding IE's interpretation of CSS, not it failing to load external CSS files. Pretty different NIMISHAN

Comment: Thanks Alireza, switching to `float:left;` fixed the issue.